# java.net.SocketTimeoutException in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jackson, jersey, glassfish

I have a spring boot application running on tomcat. The application is very lightweight like 15ms SLA but serves good traffic between 5000 and 10000 per second. The typical incoming payload size between 1 and 1.5Kb.

For very few requests (like < 5) I see the below exception while JSON deserializing the incoming payload. Struggling to triage beyond some point.

The exception happens after 20 seconds it started deserializing because 20 seconds is the SO_timeout.

But I don't know why it is waiting because I found that it read all the data and populated the POJO. I found this by adding a log in the setter method of POJO. The logs show that all the data are deserialized in one millisecond but somehow the NioBlockingSelector is waiting to read.

Code I wrote in setter Method of Pojo that helps identify whether it stuck before or after receiving the data. It received all the data.

```
public void setValue(String value){
  this.value = value;
  Sysout.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

```
st=java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:204)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:221)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1226)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1144)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:735)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:41)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:102)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:246)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:336)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:362)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream.read(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:297)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:205)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2932)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:964)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:376)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1574)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:965)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:838)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:45)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProv
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: nope. i just suppressed the exception and moved ahead. kept less SO_timeout that way i dont keep on waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the connectionTimeout of the tomcat connector setting(server.xml).
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

The default value is 20000 ms(20s).